# Is there a way to log the actually executed SQL query from Simple.Data?

Tags: simple.data

I'm looking for a feature much like the [Log property in Linq DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All executed SQL is written to the Trace, so you can access is using a TraceListener.